# Twitter Typeahead Not displaying last element

Tags: javascript, css, thymeleaf, twitter-typeahead

I'm new to Twitter Typeahead (using typeahead.js 0.11.1) and I'm trying to configure it with Thymeleaf + Spring MVC using the remote option. I have this issue where not all of the results are being displayed in the suggestions drop down menu. The last element of the results returned is not displaying.

For example, for testing purpose, I have set the minLength option to '1'. In my database, I have users with the following first names; Ron, Jon, Tom. So, when I enter the letter 'o' in the typeahead input field I am expecting all three of those names to be displayed in the suggestions menu. However, only 2 names are displayed. I have checked the response parameters (using Firebug) and can confirm that all three names are being returned. But only 2 results are being displayed, i.e. the last element is not being displayed.

Here is the javascript code:

```
// constructs the suggestion engine
var firstNames = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: '/hub/get_user_firstname_suggestions.json?searchTerm=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
});

//Initialize the Bloodhound suggestion engine
firstNames.initialize(); 

$('#firstName').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
},
{
    name: 'firstNames',
    source: firstNames.ttAdapter()
});
```

Here is screenshot of the results:
[image]

Input Html code:

```
<input th:id="${heading.fieldName}" class="typeahead" type="text" th:placeholder="${heading.value}" />
```

CSS file:

```
.typeahead,
.tt-query,
.tt-hint {
    font-weight: normal;
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 30px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;*/
  border: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
          border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

.typeahead {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 2px;
}

.typeahead:focus {
  border: 1px solid #0097cf;
}

.tt-query {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}

.tt-hint {
  color: #999
}

.tt-menu {
    font-weight: normal;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 2px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
          border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
          box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.tt-suggestion {
  padding: 3px 3px;
}

.tt-suggestion:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;
}

.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;

}

.tt-suggestion p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Am I missing something out?

Any help will be much appreciated.

UPDATE --

Ok, now I have the following strange behaviour:

If response contains 3 results, i.e. JSON response = ["Jon", "Ron", "Tom"] then upon entering the letter 'o' in the input field only the first two results appear in the suggestions menu, i.e. Jon, Ron.

If response contains 4 results, i.e. JSON response = ["Jon", "Ron", "Tom", "Thomas"] then upon entering the letter 'o' in the input field only the FIRST result appears in the suggestions menu, i.e. Jon.

This issue only occurs when using the remote option. Using the local option works fine.

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle which would demonstrate how not all source elements are shown?

Comment: goto `http://localhost:8080/hub/get_user_firstname_suggestions.json?searchTerm=o` and let me know the output of it.

Comment: @FarajFarook Following is the output: ["Jon","Ron","Tom"]

Comment: Ok. I added a new user with name 'Thomas'. Now, if I run my application and enter the letter 'o' in the input field then only the first result is shown in the suggestions dropdown menu.

Comment: Did you get this issue resolved as I'm not facing the very same problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but with the method of trail and error and some debugging I found out that if I set the Bloodhound's limit myself it works fine.

`var provider = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            limit:10,
            remote: {
                url : '...',
                wildcard : '%QUERY',
            }
        });`

Also it worth mentioning that this is for typeahead.js 0.10.5, when I test with typeahead.js 0.11.1 it is not working

Comment: I had the same problem. The "key-row" was the limit. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: use a better mantained [repo](https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js)

Just faced this problem today..

After debugging and search, it comes out that this is a known [bug](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1415).

There's also at least 2 known fix but unfortunately none of them has been committed to the code.

For those who are looking for a quick fix:

**Option 1:**

Define a greater *limit* settings into your datasource configuration, but keep in mind that this is just a workaround, probnlem persist if result of match reaches the limit value.

```
$('#firstName').typeahead({
 hint: true,
 highlight: true,
 minLength: 1
},
{
limit: 100, // here
 name: 'firstNames',
 source: firstNames
});
```

**Option 2 (suggested):**

Apply the fix manually in typeahead.bundle(*).js:

Look for *function async(suggestions) {* method for *Dataset* object and move the *rendered += suggestions.length;* after the _append call:

```
//rendered += suggestions.length; // this was before
that._append(query, suggestions.slice(0, that.limit - rendered));
rendered += suggestions.length; // move it afteer _append
```

or use only *limit* value in as parameter:

```
that._append(query, suggestions.slice(0, that.limit));
```